# Launching Tom Tom Navigation via Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, tomtom

I was looking for paid alternatives to Google Navigation Beta.

I came across Sygic and discovered ways to launch it from within an app. However, my boss wants me to use TomTom Navigation. I searched for quite a while but couldn't discover any way to launch it from within an app.

What I want to do? Call an intent, feed it latitude and longitude (or address), and launch TomTom to navigate.

Comment: When you contacted TomTom to ask them if they had an SDK for integrating with their Android app, what did they tell you?

Comment: Why do I feel as if I'm being scolded? :p
I'll email them right away and update the post if I get an answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Got their reply. Their rep didn't seem to have much technical knowledge. The reply was NO.

Now can you research a bit and tell me?

Comment: If TomTom wanted you to integrate with their app, they would publish instructions for doing so. I presume that you visited the TomTom site and came up with nothing. Since the person you talked to also indicated that they did not support this, I am not quite certain what you are expecting anyone else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this should be an answer but I just wanted to close this question..

Its NOT possible to do so. Here is the reply to my second query (I re-confirmed because I thought the tech-support guy hadn't gotten what I wanted)

> Dear Asim,
>
> This is Seren once again from TomTom Customer Support with your query
>   reference number 130102-002150.
>
> First of all, I would like to apologize for the inconvenience and the
>   confusion caused due to my previous reply.
>
> Please be assured that we always have the best of intentions of
>   providing outstanding customer service to our customers, and we will
>   do our best to address any issues you may have.
>
> Asim, I have re confirmed with one of my senior team member and like
>   to inform you that as of now we do not have an app from which you can
>   be called on from within another Android app.
>
> However, as your suggestion is a very good one. I have taken your
>   feedback and forwarded to our product management team.
>
> Our Product Managers review all feedback to determine future
>   enhancements and products. Many of our current products and updates
>   offer features based on customer suggestions. We certainly value our
>   esteemed customers like you.
>
> we hope you find this information helpful.
>
> If you have any further query, please get back to us and we will
>   assist you further.

Comment: But the answer looks like the think about adding this feature in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Has become possible](http://discussions.tomtom.com/t5/TomTom-Navigation-app-for/TomTom-Url-scheme-for-Android/td-p/431046), according to the TomTom forum.

Comment: I am doing this with Automate 1.21.2 and TomTom GO 1.28.1 release/1.18 (2169), so clearly it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

TomTom has several API's to either use their content (http://developer.tomtom.com) or allow communication with their professional navigation through their WEBFLEET.api (http://business.tomtom.com/en_gb/fleet-management/integration/resources/).